# EE1 to EE2: Better to Upgrade or Migrate?

Tags: ee2-upgrades, datagrab

Looking to get some opinions form people who have "been there done that" on getting from EE1 to EE2.

I'm working on a site that's currently running EE 1.6.9. As a first step towards the redesign I'd like to get them on to the latest version of EE, and it seems I have a couple options:

1. Update to EE 1.7.2, then use the standard EE2 upgrade wizard, and do some cleanup on the EE2 end (if I get there).
2. Setup a new EE2 install with similar data structure, and pull over the data with something like Data Grab.

I seem to be finding horror stories from folks on both sides. There are a lot of (old) plugins in play … most have EE2 versions, but some very key ones don't:

- Gypsy
- Matrix
- Playa (which is holding a ton of relationships we'd hate to have to recreate)
- Wygwam
- Better Meta
- LG Image Manager (which I guess will have to switch to Assets)
- LG TinyMCE (which I guess we'll ultimately switch to Wygwam)
- nGen File Field

Initially, I started down the first path. But maybe the second option is cleaner (though I worry about if/how the playa relationships will be migrated, etc.)?

Honestly, it all feels like a mess, so before I venture any further figured I'd ping the community for advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a time-sink no matter how you approach it. Gypsy is the big red flag in the EE1 install as it fundamentally changed how EE works at a low-level. There is an "undo-Gypsy" add-on (https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/undo-gypsy) but as you can see it's unsupported. The nGen file field will also need some db-level SQL to change to a native file field.

It's tough to say based on the data you've provided (not sure what a "ton" of relationships means etc) but overall unless you are talking about thousands of entries I'd probably lean towards a fresh build in EE2, importing what you can, and then manual editing from there.

But you might try an upgrade approach on a copy of everything just to see what happens as well.

Comment: Following up: I ended up using undo-gypsy per Michael's advice. From there I used the [Weblog Entries Exporter plugin](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/weblog-entries-exporter) to get entries out of EE1 and into .csv's, which I was then able to manipulate in Google Docs (which didn't muck up the encoding and has a regex find and replace feature). Once I touched up the data, I imported the .csv's into a fresh EE2 install using the [Datagrab plugin](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab). It took some trial and error, but once this process was down it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I never did a big upgrade, just small updates.

I guess it depends on the size of the database of the site (entries, relationships, members etc). If it's a small database, perhaps would be better to migrate (no headache with compatibility problems), but if it's a huge one, would be better to upgrade.